# Почему в этом коде не работает mysqli_num_rows?

Tags: php

`mysqli_num_rows` у меня на многих файлах и работает нормально, а на этом пишет

```
\ Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in \
```

Подскажите пожалуйста по какой причине это может быть ?

```
if(isset($_POST['label']))
$r=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM akk WHERE id_akk='".$_POST['label']."'");
$nr=mysqli_num_rows($r);
if(!$nr) exit();

mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO plateg (summa, id_akk, typ, data, opis)  VALUES ('".$_POST['amount']."', '".$_POST['label']."', 1, NOW(), 'Пополнение кошелька через Яндекс.Деньги')");

include('../../balans.php');
```

Comment: Вообще странно. Это сообщение об ошибке вообще от этого кода? mysqli_query по идее не может вернуть null

Comment: Но самое забавное конечно не это, а то что кто угодно может налить себе сколько угодно денег или вообще постирать все платежи